# Chrome extension doesn't work in Linux (works in windows)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-platform

Okay, this is weird.
[This is my extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sheen/mopkplcglehjfbedbngcglkmajhflnjk), and it works flawlessly in Windows (atleast on two win7 machines), but when I tested it on linux (CentOS6 and Fedora18) it failed to do anything when its icon was clicked (it should, at the very least, display an `alert`).
The options page still works, and saves data properly.

After enabling `developer mode` in `chrome://extensions/` you can click `_generated_background_page.html` for the extension to see the JS console for the addon.

That's where I saw the following error:

```
Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "https://www.google.com.au/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

<sub>actual url in error is not relevant, does it to all sites</sub>

Thing is, the windows machines showed no such error, shouldn't this be platform independent?
The manifests are obviously the same, so how come the addon hasn't the required permissions *only on linux machines*?

<sub>Mac is untested, if someone could try that for me, it might be useful</sub>

---

**FURTHER INFORMATION**

The error message above was given with the following information;
Located in the function `chromeHidden.handleResponse` on line `22` of the script `sendRequest`

Comment: The [`activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html) permission was added in Chrome 26. Make sure that you've installed Chrome/Chromium 26+.

Comment: I am using `activeTab`, and the linux computers are stuck at v25 until the repos are pushed. This is an acceptable answer if you make it one, thanks! (thought I somehow wrote it [the software] wrong xD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"activeTab"` permission was added in Chrome 26. Make sure that you've installed Chrome/Chromium 26+.

If you want to make your extension compatible with older browsers in the Chrome Web Store, add host permissions to the manifest file, plus the `minimum_chrome_version` key:

First upload an extension with the following manifest file:

```js
{
    "name": "Name of extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

Then bump the version, change `"<all_urls>"` to `"activeTab"`, add the `"minimum_chrome_version"` field and upload it again to the Chrome Web Store:

```js
{
    "name": "Name of extension",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "minimum_chrome_version": "26.0.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Just found a linux machine with v28, worked, thanks for the tips

Comment: I would've thought Chrome (25) would have complained when I tried to use a term in the JSON it didn't recognise. I know my 28 at home did when I misspelt something in it.